# How to communicate between two C# applications(sending messages and receiving messages)?

Tags: c#, signalr, messaging

As per my knowledge, I knew that messages can posted from one application to other application using "`SendMessage`" or "`PostMessage`".

I tried using SignalR to communicate b/w the applications. The problem here i found was server should be launched as a console application and clients will be my winforms. Ideally I don't want to show this console application as it seems to be weird for the user. If there is any work around for this approach please suggest.

After `signalR` I came across `EventAggregrator` in c#. Can we use `EventAggregrator` to communicate b/w two different `C# applications`? If yes could some one give an example on how to do this.

Comment: Create a windows service and move the logic from your console app into the service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Comment: UDP can also be used to communicate between apps, its rather easy to use

Comment: Adding to @Kell comment, implement an IpcChannel between the two https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: @Kell, Thanks for your reply. If I create this as a windows service I need to start and stop the service right. I don't want any user intervention. Just I want send messages b/w two apps. Can't we do it using EventAggregrator pattern?

Comment: yes. Alternatively you could just create an asp.net web serivce and communicate with http. It depends on whether your service is running on the same machine, domain or network as the winforms app.

Answer (score 0):

Until a few years ago, Socket class was the right way to do this. There are probably more modern, robust and easier ways to achieve the same result nowadays, but you may want to look at what's under the hood.

#### Socket class on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

#### Client-server example on CodeProject:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/463947/working-with-sockets-in-csharp